# How Can I View Multiple Page Source Code?

Tags: html, web-scraping, browser, visual-web-developer

How can I view Multiple Page Source Code - all together in one set. 
for example:

- https://stackoverflow.com/
- https://www.microsoft.com/
- https://www.example.com/

Every URL of these has a page source, how can I view them all under/into one set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't know why this question got -1 vote.
however, the answer that I've found it might fit this question is that you can go to this link:

- https://www.joydeepdeb.com/tools/view-source-code.html

Inside this link there's a useful tool might help other similar purposes.
This tool offers limited use, which means that, some URLs might not properly work, I think it is because the syntax of the URL must take a certain form/shape.

Comment: however, I'm still looking for an advanced answer that might help.